# API or library to get a snippet or summary from a webpage

Tags: python, summary, data-extraction

I want to give a URL and get a summary. Is there a library or an API to do this?

I am working with Python, but I can port from other languages.

Comment: What is a summary?  All the text on the page?  The page title?  Something else?

Comment: Summary is applying some sort of heuristics to get a representative text from the page. (Similar to what happens when you enter a link in FB share box.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like urllib or urllib2?

Both of those libraries allow you to retrieve information from a specified URL.  Here's a (slightly dated) introduction I found with a quick search.

http://www.codercaste.com/2009/11/28/how-to-use-the-urllib-python-library-to-fetch-url-data-and-more/